# How to prevent Nuance's DragonMobile from turning off VoiceOver?

Tags: ios, accessibility, screen-readers, voiceover

Nuance's DragonMobile component apparently turns off VoiceOver announcements between the initial call to `SKRecognizer`'s `initWithType:detection:language:delegate` and the component's call to `recognizerDidFinishRecording:`. It makes some sense that they do this, since they don't want the VoiceOver announcements to be picked up by the mic and transcribed.

The problem is that there's usually a 1-2 second gap between the initialization of the recognizer and the initial call to `recognizerDidBeginRecording:`. In order to prevent the user's first few words from getting cut out of the transcription, it's necessary to use `recognizerDidBeginRecording:` to indicate to the user that they should start speaking (i.e. you can't just have them hit the mic button and start speaking immediately).

My problem is that since DragonMobile turns off VoiceOver as soon as `initWithType:` is called, I have no way of indicating to a VoiceOver user that they should begin talking at the appropriate time.

Comment: VoiceOver (VO) and DragonMobile (DM) are intended  for two different groups of people with disabilities. VO is for people who are blind or have low vision. DM is geared for people who have mobility (no pun intended) issues. So I would say, unless you have a use case, I would not say there is an issuec

Comment: @RyanB: DragonMobile is not geared for people with mobility issues; it's geared for anyone who wishes to talk instead of typing. Typing with VoiceOver is a monstrous PITA, and all of my VoiceOver testers prefer to use the DM speech recognition instead. So I definitely have a use case.

Comment: The intent of the Dragon line of products is to assist those who could not use the mouse. Only a few years ago, they revamped the product so it was more marketable to a wider range of people. People want to use dragon vs whatever's built in is because the quality. Also going on the fact that Dragon relies on visually seeing the screen to operate, and VoiceOver doesn't, the two fight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found something of a workaround: DragonMobile allows you to specify `SKEarcon`s, which are audio files that play whenever recording is started, stopped or canceled. I'm going to record VoiceOver making the announcements that I need and then use these recordings as the earcons, so that it will sound like the rest of VoiceOver.

According to a Nuance technical rep I just spoke to, DragonMobile does indeed take over the audio layer and suppress any output during recording, and they don't expose any way around this other than the earcons.